# 'raise' causes SyntaxError

Tags: python

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import ast

def main(argv):
  for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
      rules, scores = line.split('\t')
      scores = ast.literal_eval(scores)
      print '\t'.join([rules, str(any(scores))])
    except:
      sys.stderr.write('Got line ' + line)
      raise

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main(sys.argv[0]) # 0 as there are no args besides the hive query fields
```

The script works as expected for the expected input

```
$ echo -e "[{2,3},{4,3}]\t[1]" | ./check_anom.py
[{2,3},{4,3}]   True
```

But when there's an error in the input:

```
$ echo -e "[{2,3},{4,3}]\t" | ./check_anom.py
Got line [{2,3},{4,3}]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./check_anom.py", line 19, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[0]) # 0 as there are no args besides the hive query fields
  File "./check_anom.py", line 12, in main
    scores = ast.literal_eval(scores)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

I would have expected a ValueError, why do I get SyntaxError?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to `eval("")` because your `[1]` is missing behind the `\t` on which you `split`. It's in your first command but not in the one that throws an error.

Raise is not causing the syntax error, `eval("")` is causing a syntax error, raise simply raises it.